# Laravel avoid overlapping dates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and am trying to implement reservation dates that can not overlap on any day.

I have a model called 'Bookings' that includes the room_id, start_date and end_date.

I have validation that checks that the end date can not be before the start:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => 'required|date',
        'end_date' => 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

However I am not sure how to check that the date range does not conflict with any other date ranges of the same room_id stored in the bookings table (as one room can not be booked twice in the same range).

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to check that in database. So you can do this:

```
$result = Bookings::where('start_date', '<=' $request->start_date)->where('end_date', '>=' $request->end_date)->where('room_id',$request->room_id)->first();
if(!$result){
  // Code to Book room
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In a typical overlaping, given two events A and B, you have to consider four scenarios:

1. Event A contains event B
2. Event B contains event A
3. End date of event A overlaps with start date of event B
4. End date of event B overlaps with start date of event A

So, in sql to check if a room is busy in a interval of dates, lets say 2018-11-20' and '2018-11-30' it would be:

```
select * 
from rooms 
where 
    start_date between '2018-11-20' and '2018-11-30' or 
    end_date between '2018-11-20' and '2018-11-30' or 
    '2018-11-20' between start_date and end_date or 
    '2018-11-30' between start_date and end_date;
```

In laravel what I do is to create a scope in the model.

```
public function scopeByBusy($query,$start_date,$end_date) 
{ 
    return $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$start_date, $end_date]) 
        ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$start_date, $end_date]) 
        ->orWhereRaw('? BETWEEN start_date and end_date', [$start_date]) 
        ->orWhereRaw('? BETWEEN start_date and end_date', [$end_date]); 
}
```

Finally, I can verify if the room with the id 95 is busy between '2018-11-20' and '2018-11-30' like this:

```
$room_id = 95;
$start = '2018-11-20';
$end = '2018-11-30';
$exists = Rooms::where('id', $room_id)
    ->byBusy($start, $end)
    ->first();

if($exists)
{
    echo "the room is busy in the interval you selected";
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Very nice first answer. I had a quick go on your post and changed the formatting to what is commonly used on stack overflow. Also I fixed an SQL injection vulnerability in the second code block. You'd want to use the query builders ability to bind parameters for you, otherwise the query is not safe. But nonetheless, good answer!

Comment: Thanks @Namoshek I have been playing with Laravel and other things for a while, but I had never given an answer, I think It is time to share what I have learnt with others :). Thanks for correcting me. It is a good point. Security. I didn't consider that because the dates have to pass a validator request with rules ['required', 'date_format:d/m/Y'], and even a use a custom rule object to verify that the second date is greater or equal than first date. Then when the dates get to the controller I format them to the database format 'Y-m-d', then I use the scope of the model.

Comment: I am a little bit late but does `orWhereRaw`s necessary? I think two conditions are enough. The later ones are unnecessary checks.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar usage where i needed to check if person has already scheduled something in date range

An example laravel code below :

```
 $start = Carbon::parse($request['start_date'])->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
 $end = Carbon::parse($request['end_date'])->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
 $existsActive = Microsite::where(function ($query) use ($start) {
                                      $query->where('start_date', '<=', $start);
                                      $query->where('end_date', '>=', $start);
                                  })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($end) {
                                      $query->where('start_date', '<=', $end);
                                      $query->where('end_date', '>=', $end);
                                  })->count();
 if($existsActive > 0 ){
    echo "Already exists";  
 }
```

Comment: I just wanted to check if I have any overlapping entries exists in the database. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's built-in Carbon method isPast() so you can use:

```
$start_date->isPast()
$end_date->isPast()
```

You can check If both selected were booked in past.

If you haven't used Carbon this is the link:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(DB::table('rooms')->whereBetween('start_date', [$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
    ->orwhereBetween('end_date',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])->exists())
{
  echo "the room is busy in the interval you selected";
}
```